# Link : Use ojects and baked simulation in another .blend

Tags: physics, linked-data

I made a simulation with a bunch of objects and rigid body constraints in file1.blend. 
I would like to use it in another file (file2.blend).

I guess I need to link the object and the baked simulation. ( Note that I couldn't find the bake options in my 2.82 version, for instance the *Use Library Path* option ).

I could use some help ...

Thanks !

Comment: You are right Jachym. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Collection Instances* for that.

1. Put all your simulation objects inside a Collection
2. Link that Collection into another file (using *File > Link*). That will create an *Instance*.
3. Move your linked *Collection Instance* as one object

*Linked simulation from another file then behaves like one object.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jachym, Points 1, 2, 3 are ok. But the linked object is motionless in File2, although simulation works and is baked in File1.

Comment: Hi :). Would you mind sharing the files? I'd like to take a closer look at what might be wrong :).

Comment: That's really kind of you. First file with the simulation :  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zw3NMzBl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zw3NMzBl/)   Second file that imports the simulation :     ( It was too big, I had to remove almost everything ... except the important for us ) ... one minute please ...

Comment: Here is the second file :   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YmZy6pMO" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YmZy6pMO/)

Comment: Hello :). Please post it as a new question, add the files and somebody will surely help :). There are many people waaay more skilled than me.